# Git remote repo shows no merge conflicts, but locally git is showing many of them

Tags: git, gitlab

not sure what is really happening, but gitlab is showing no merge conflicts and that it's ready to merge, but after pulling latest main and the other branch, when I try to rebase it's showing thousands of conflicts (when those shouldn't be conflicts).

Any ideas what is happening? Tried even deleting and cloning repo again.

Comment: Rebase and merge are different. Your local test should do the same merge that Gitlab does instead of a rebase.

Answer (score 3):

`Merge` only compares latest commits of two branches. However `rebase` needs to replay each commit in the rebased branch on the base branch. One or more of those commits may have conflicts with the latest commit of the base branch. It is possible to have conflicting intermediate commits but still have non conflicting final commit.

Comment: Right on target. To the OP: Try merging instead of rebasing and tell us how it goes.